# How to Navigate from Splash Screen to a StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack route of go_router Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I am developing a Mobile App where the App starts from a
**SplashScreen** and Navigates go **HomeScreen** which is implemented under **`StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack`** that contains **BottomNavigationBar** and each screens of contains multiple routes.

When the splash screens completes its 3 second animation, I intend to make the app load the **HomeScreen**.

Here is the snippet from the
`splash_screen.dart`

```
Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        // TODO: How to navigate to StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack here instead of context.goNamed('home')
        isOnboardingCompleted ? isLoggedIn ? context.goNamed('home') 
                : context.goNamed('signin')
            : context.goNamed('onboarding');
      },
    );
  }
```

and  snippet from `gorouter.dart`

```
late final router = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: appStateProvider,
    initialLocation: '/splash-screen',
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: [
      /// splash
      GoRoute(
        path: '/splash-screen',
        name: 'splash',
        builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
      ),

      ///
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
          return HomeScreen(navigationShell: navigationShell);
        },
        branches: [
          // first branch (Account)
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorAccountKey,
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: '/account',
                name: 'account',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  return CustomTransitionPage(
                    child: const AccountScreen(),
                    transitionsBuilder:
                        (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                      return FadeTransition(
                        opacity:
                            CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear).animate(animation),
                        child: child,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'personal-info',
                    name: 'personalinfo',
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                      return CustomTransitionPage(
                        child: const PersonalInfoScreen(),
                        transitionsBuilder:
                            (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                          return FadeTransition(
                            opacity: CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)
                                .animate(animation),
                            child: child,
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
    
.......
```

Please, kindly help me how can I redirect to **HomeScreen** from **SplashScreen**

Answer (score 1):

Using `ShellRoute` or `StatefulShellRoute` is for having an additional `Navigator` placed in the widget tree to be used instead of the root navigator. **These shell-route widgets are NOT routes themselves, they are a wrapper around other routes to share a common internal navigator and UI elements**. See more information and examples in the [official docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html).

The widget that is provided in the `builder` function of the `StatefulShellRoute` (*`HomeScreen`* in your example) is just a *shell*, i.e. a wrapper to show UI elements which are common to those routes. That widget is usually just a `Scaffold` with a bottom nav bar or any other common UI/UX elements.

In the shell-route the *`StatefulNavigationShell`* is passed to be able access the *state* of the shell, and to navigate to other branches in a "stateful way" (using `goBranch()`)

Outside the "shellroute" you navigate to those routes as you would to any other route, using `context.goNamed(nameOfTheRoute)` or `context.go(pathOfTheRoute)`. In your example you shall define somewhere those *home*, *sigin* and *onboading* routes.

For example, if you would like to have three routes "/a", "/b" and "/c", which are within a shell, and you would like to navigate to route "/a" by `context.go("/a")` in your timer, you shall implement the following:

```dart
StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state,
            StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {
          return HomeScreen(navigationShell: navigationShell);
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          // The route branch for the first tab of the bottom navigation bar.
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _sectionANavigatorKey,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                // The screen to display in the first tab of the
                // bottom navigation bar.
                path: '/a',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const ScreenAShellBody(),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          // The route branch for the second tab of the bottom navigation bar.
          StatefulShellBranch(
            // It's not necessary to provide a navigatorKey if it isn't also
            // needed elsewhere. If not provided, a default key will be used.
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                // The screen to display as the shell body in the second tab of the bottom navigation bar.
                path: '/b',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const ScreenBShellBody(),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                // The screen to display as the shell body in the third tab of the
                // bottom navigation bar.
                path: '/c',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const ScreenCShellBody(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    naivigate();
}
void naivigate() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
    isOnboardingCompleted
        ? isLoggedIn
            ? context.goNamed('home')
            : context.goNamed('signin')
        : context.goNamed('onboarding');
    });
  }
```

> you can put the navigation logic in initState like above.